# How to Create an Access Report for a Cash Flow Financial Statement requiring calculations on multiple fields

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access DB set up with monthly financial data results in several tables:
 - Account Balances: Account#, BegBal, EndBal, Month, Year - 1 record per account per month/year
 - Account Numbers: Account#, Description, CF Line Item#
 - Cash Flow Def: CF Line Item#, Description

The Cash Flow report is similar to the following:
CF Line Item 1    "Description"         Sum of All Accounts for CF Line Item 1 (EndBal-Beg Bal)
CF Line Item 2    "Description"         Sum of All Accounts for CF Line Item 2 (EndBal-Beg Bal)
…

Cash flow report for a given month was pretty straight forward. I am having issues creating one that also includes a column for YTD Results.  That requires me to use the Account Balance table records for 2 different months (easy enough to add to the select query criteria) but not sure how to:
1 - create an expression that references the EndBal from Current Month Record and the Start Balance from the January Month Record
2 - create the report such that the summation properly handles the fact that there are 2 account balance records per account (1 for January and 1 for Current Month).
3 - I thought of using a Self Join first but a further complication arises since the Account#'s can be added and stopped.  So we need to be inclusive of cases where Account# is not in Current Month but is in the January month and visa-versa.  The other Month would then just be a value of 0.

EDIT 4/9/2020

OK, So I think I have mostly solved my problem.  I needed a FULL OUTER JOIN on the same table to get my desired results - but of course Access does not directly support this - needed to do a UNION of a LEFT and RIGHT OUTER JOIN.

**See below for the SQL**

SELECT a.RecDate, a.StoreID, a.[Account#], a.[Beginning Balance],  a.[End Balance],  b.RecDate,  b.StoreID, b.[Account#], b.[Beginning Balance]
FROM (
   (SELECT * FROM AccountBalances WHERE (AccountBalances.RecDate=[TempVars]![varDate]  AND AccountBalances.StoreID=[TempVars]![varStoreID])) AS a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM AccountBalances WHERE (AccountBalances.RecDate=[TempVars]![varStartDate]  AND AccountBalances.StoreID=[TempVars]![varStoreID])) AS b
   ON  (a.[Account#]=b.[Account#])
)

UNION

SELECT a.RecDate, a.StoreID, a.[Account#], a.[Beginning Balance],  a.[End Balance],  b.RecDate,  b.StoreID, b.[Account#], b.[Beginning Balance]
FROM (
   (SELECT * FROM AccountBalances WHERE (AccountBalances.RecDate=[TempVars]![varDate]  AND AccountBalances.StoreID=[TempVars]![varStoreID])) AS a
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM AccountBalances WHERE (AccountBalances.RecDate=[TempVars]![varStartDate]  AND AccountBalances.StoreID=[TempVars]![varStoreID])) AS b
   ON  (a.[Account#]=b.[Account#])
);
Mike

Comment: See if you can get some clues from Allen Browne: http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html. When you have some code with specific issue, post question.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to use a FULL OUTER JOIN but of course Access does not directly support that so used a UNION of LEFT and RIGHT OUTER JOINs - see below.

SELECT a.RecDate, a.StoreID, a.[Account#], a.[Beginning Balance],  a.[End Balance],  b.RecDate,  b.StoreID, b.[Account#], b.[Beginning Balance]

FROM (

(SELECT * FROM AccountBalances WHERE (AccountBalances.RecDate=[TempVars]![varDate]  AND AccountBalances.StoreID=[TempVars]![varStoreID])) AS a

LEFT OUTER JOIN

(SELECT * FROM AccountBalances WHERE (AccountBalances.RecDate=[TempVars]![varStartDate]  AND AccountBalances.StoreID=[TempVars]![varStoreID])) AS b

ON  (a.[Account#]=b.[Account#])

)

UNION

SELECT a.RecDate, a.StoreID, a.[Account#], a.[Beginning Balance],  a.[End Balance],  b.RecDate,  b.StoreID, b.[Account#], b.[Beginning Balance]

FROM (

(SELECT * FROM AccountBalances WHERE (AccountBalances.RecDate=[TempVars]![varDate]  AND AccountBalances.StoreID=[TempVars]![varStoreID])) AS a

RIGHT OUTER JOIN

(SELECT * FROM AccountBalances WHERE (AccountBalances.RecDate=[TempVars]![varStartDate]  AND AccountBalances.StoreID=[TempVars]![varStoreID])) AS b

ON  (a.[Account#]=b.[Account#])

);